# Mocking an entire function with parameters in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have this Python code normally running on a distant server that I want to test locally:

```python
from af.data import Variable

def create_file():
    main_client = file.Client()
    directory = main_client.create(Variable.get("DIR_NAME"))
```

As I am developing locally and do not have access to the remote service providing the `af.data.Variable` class, I'd like to mock the `Variable.get(str)` function, but I'd like to be able—in my own mock—to return some value based on the passed the `str` parameter. So far, I've found only ways to mock a function to some pre-defined static values using side_effect of unittest.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you see the 3rd example in the unittest quick guide: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide. You can use `side_effect` to point to your made-up test function which can take arguments and have the logic you want.

Comment: Hello Peter, indeed, I was mixing up the side_effect examples with the class instantiation behavior. I didn't know it would work for functions as well. Thanks for the hint, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the Peter's comment, here is the solution (pretty straightforward):

```python
from unittest.mock import Mock
from af.data import Variable
import os

def side_effect(arg):
   """Put here whatever logic you want to put in your mock, here's an example of reading a system environment variable"""
    return os.getenv(arg)

mock = Mock()
mock.get.side_effect = side_effect
Variable = mock

"""Then just use the Variable.get method as you would do in production environment, it should be mocked to the side_effect function declared above"""
```